# Pictures are not deleted from "Photos" iphone app when deleted from "Google Photos"

Tags: photos, photos.app, google

When I delete a picture from "Google Photos" on my iphone it is not deleted from the "Photos" app. How to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When deleting on my iPhone, it asks if I will "Allow "GooglePhotos" to delete this photo? This photo will be deleted from iCloud Photo Library on all your devices." I can choose not to allow it and it will only be deleted on my Google Photos app.

I evidently have iCloud Photo Library turned on, and backup and sync on the Google Photos app turned on as well.

Also, check on Settings > Privacy > Photos to see if Google Photos is allowed to access your pictures.